# Tabbing environment with automatic tab stops

Tags: loops, tabbing

I'm attempting to define a custom tabbing environment which allows me to align subsequent lines of text with elements in a previously generated block which *cannot* be inside the tabbing environment.  So far this is what I've got:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[savepos]{zref}

\newenvironment{nstabbing}
  {\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
   \setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}%
   \tabbing}
  {\endtabbing\setcounter{tabstop}{0}}

\newcounter{tabstop}
\newcommand{\align}{%
    \stepcounter{tabstop}%
    \expandafter\zsavepos{stop\thetabstop}%
}

\begin{document}
First{\align} I have{\align} something{\align} which sets{\align} the alignment {\align}points.
\begin{nstabbing}
\hspace*{-\oddsidemargin}\hspace{-1in}\hspace{\zposx{stop1} sp}\=%
\hspace{-\zposx{stop1} sp}\hspace{\zposx{stop2} sp}\=%
\hspace{-\zposx{stop2} sp}\hspace{\zposx{stop3} sp}\=%
\hspace{-\zposx{stop3} sp}\hspace{\zposx{stop4} sp}\=%
\hspace{-\zposx{stop4} sp}\hspace{\zposx{stop5} sp}\=%
\kill
\>Some\>thing\>using\>those\>alignment points.\\
\end{nstabbing}

\end{document}
```

*Note:* For the purposes of this MWE I've substituted simple text for the block which generates the alignment points in order to minimize the number of packages needed for the MWE.  Moving this block inside the tabbing environment is *not* possible in the actual use case.

This works, but constructing the kill line manually is overly complicated, especially when the number of tab stops increases (I might have up to 20 or so in some use cases).  What I'd like to do is automate that so that it can be part of the custom environment definition.

The way I figure, I know how many tab stops need to be defined and what their names are when the environment starts based on the current value of the counter `tabstop`.  What I need to do then, is loop over the locations in some fashion to define each one.  Does anyone have any suggestions for how I might modify the definition of `nstabbing` so that it does this automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a different definition of `\align` (and I suggest a different name, because `\align` is taken by `amsmath`) and also a `\setstops` macro that you can possibly add to the definition of `nstabbing`, if you prefer.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[savepos]{zref}

\newenvironment{nstabbing}
  {\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
   \setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}%
   \tabbing}
  {\endtabbing\setcounter{tabstop}{0}}

\newcounter{tabstop}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\AL}{%
  \@bsphack
  \stepcounter{tabstop}%
  \expandafter\zsavepos{stop\thetabstop}%
  \@esphack
}

\newcommand{\setstops}{%
  \gdef\nstabbing@stops{%
    \hspace*{-\oddsidemargin}\hspace{-1in}%
    \hspace{\zposx{stop1} sp}\=%
  }%
  \count@=\@ne
  \loop\ifnum\count@<\value{tabstop}%
    \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
      \noexpand\g@addto@macro\noexpand\nstabbing@stops{%
        \noexpand\hspace{-\noexpand\zposx{stop\the\count@} sp}%
        \noexpand\hspace{\noexpand\zposx{stop\the\numexpr\count@+1} sp}\noexpand\=%
      }%
    }\x
    \advance\count@\@ne
  \repeat
  \nstabbing@stops\kill
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
First \AL I have \AL something \AL which sets \AL the alignment  \AL points.
\begin{nstabbing}\setstops
\>Some\>thing\>using\>those\>alignment points.\\
\end{nstabbing}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you much.  I ended up having to add another counter to the stop name to make this reusable in the same document, but this works great.